# Eclipse RCP Adapters

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface, tableviewer, treeviewer

I have a view with a `TableViewer` of cities. I also have another view with a `TreeViewer` of persons. Can someone explain or give me a tip on how can I update the TreeViewer with persons from the city selected in `TableViewer` using adapter factory?

Comment: Try to be more specific. Post some code, tell us what have you tried and why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

it's completely necessary to use an adapter factory?

You could add a `SelectionChangedListener` in the `CityTreeViewer` (maybe if the query of people from one city is expensive you can add a `PostSelectionChangedListener`) to update the input of the `TreeViewer` of People when the selection treeViewer of City changed.